# jQuery UI, draggable / sortable append problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to append html to an item which I have successfully dragged to a sortable list but it does not seem to work. I am cloning the original item and have tried to append to the ui.helper to no avail.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#sortable3").sortable({
            revert: true,
            receive: function(ev, ui) {
                ui.item.append("Tsfsdfg");
                save_object(ui.item);
            }

        });

        $('li',"#sortable1").draggable({
            connectToSortable: '#sortable3',
            helper: 'clone',
            revert: 'invalid',

        });

        function save_object($item) {
            var the_id = $item.attr('id');
            $item.append("This is it");
            $item.slideUp(500,function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });




        }


        $("#sortable1, #sortable3").disableSelection();
    });
    </script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="demo">

<ul id="sortable1">
    <li id="mx-101" class="ui-state-default">Num 1 <img src="images/icon_alert.png" alt="" /> </li>
    <li id="mx-102" class="ui-state-default">Num 2 <img src="images/icon_clock.png" alt="" /></li>
    <li id="mx-103" class="ui-state-default">Num 3 <img src="images/icon_congrats.png" alt="" /></li>
    <li id="mx-104" class="ui-state-default">Num 4 <img src="images/icon_delete.png" alt="" /></li>
    <li id="mx-105" class="ui-state-default">Num 5 <img src="images/icon_add.png" alt="" /></li>
</ul>


<ul id="sortable3">
</ul>

<br clear="both" />

</div><!-- End demo -->



</body>
```

I just want to append some sort of "un-delete" icon on the item that is dragged to the right side list so that I send it back to the original list. Can't seem to append anything to the dragged/cloned item, just the original and I am getting rid of that one.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this functionality? Should I just go with "droppable" on the right side list? I want that right side list to be sortable though.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've used in the past:

```
 function itemreceived(event, ui) {
    $(this).find("li.ui-state-highlight").removeClass("ui-state-highlight").addClass("ui-state-default");
  };
```

Just have the `<li>`s in `#sortable1` marked with a class that you remove once they've been received in `#sortable3`.

BTW - Instead of setting `#sortable1` to be draggable why not use `connectWith:` like here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists